# How to enable FontAwesome "--fa-secondary-color" feature?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to add a two tone color icon; however, adding `--fa-secondary-color` to the style doesn't add a secondary color. The color is always blue.

Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/habdeltawabae/pen/QWNxZYy

And here is a screenshot of what I am doing:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have font awesome pro? You don't get the 2 tone icons with the free version.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had the `fas` class, after removing it, it got fixed